# Count occurrence frequency across columns in pandas dataframe per datetime interval

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, count

I want to count the frequency of values in column W (df.compound) per frequency in `df.Datetime_x` (which is not set as datetime index).
As you can see below, I need the frequency per available datetime interval in `df.Datetime_x` on the same level as marked

[image]

I tried to groupby the different datetime columns and apply the count method but it does not work

Comment: what are the join keys between the two datasets?

Answer (score 0):

a datetime has the following structure

```
dt=datetime(year=2017,
month=10,
day=1,
hour=15,
minute=23,
second=25,
microsecond=500000)

dt=dt.replace(year=2018)

#you can replace an attribute of the datetime

#you can extract any part of a datetime for comparison
print(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, dt.microsecond)
#you can convert a string to a datetime
dt=pd.to_datetime("2021-02-19")
print(type(dt))

#you can format a date into datetime into string using strftime

grouped=df.groupby('datetime_column')['compound'].aggfunc(['count','sum',mean])
```